# Disable Buttons C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, visibility

The SetVisibility checks against a database if all the buttons should be enabled or not. I want to disable all buttons `if setvisility(UserID) == false`

This part of the Code disables only alternating up and down buttons. Can someone please suggest why is this happening ?

```
else
{
    Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
    b.Enabled = false;
    Button b2 = e.Item.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
    b2.Enabled = false;
}
```

Here is the Complete Code:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
{
    String userID = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
    if (setvisibility(userID) == true)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
        {
            Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
            b.Enabled = false;
        }

        DataView view = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        DataTable result = view.ToTable();
        if (e.Item.ItemIndex == (result.Rows.Count) - 1)
        {
            Button b2 = e.Item.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
            b2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else // How to disable all the buttons ? 
    {
        Button b = e.Item.FindControl("btnmoveup") as Button;
        b.Enabled = false;
        Button b2 = e.Item.FindControl("btnmovedown") as Button;
        b2.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Item.HasControls` be `Item.FindControl`?

Comment: @Duane Yes sorry i did that change now still it has the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem )
```